# Getting a list of columns by a list of identifiers

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is a Product entity.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "url_img1", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String urlImg1;
```

Product has an ID field and a urlImg field.

There is a list of Product identifiers.

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1L);
list.add(2L);
```

How can I get all urlImgs of these identifiers using JPA request?

```
@Query()
List<String> ();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a basic query like this `select p.urlImg1 from Product p where p.id in :productIds`